# Override css rendered by an advertising javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript code which loads some advertising code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://adspaces/103872.js"></script>
```

In my browser here is how my code renders:

```
<div id="content0" class="content" title="www.site.com" valign="middle">

    <div style="font-size: 12.08px; line-height: 14.08px;" class="title" id="title0">

        <a class="link" id="" href="the link" target="_blank">The anchor</a>

    </div>

   <a class="link" id="" href="the link" target="_blank"><img class="img" id="im_0" src="img src" onerror="swi(this);" onload="if(this.height >43){this.height=43;} formatAd(0);" align="left" border="0" height="43"></a>

   <div class="text" id="text0">

       <a class="link" id="" href="the link" target="_blank">The anchor</a>
       </div>

</div>
```

How can I override the css rules rendered by the javascrip. I need to put my own text site, line height, etc. Is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is the link to http://jsfiddle.net/sexywebteacher/UALr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `!important` to override the inline styles.

```
#title0 {
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Tts3u/).

Or alternatively, modify them with JavaScript.

Comment: On my site it doesn't, don't know why... it should, but it doesn't

Comment: @webmasters Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: @webmasters create a demo of your problem at http://jsfiddle.net/  without adult content.

Comment: @webmasters: Add a link to your site. It's fine, buried in a comment  here. You can remove it after your problem is solved.

Comment: I just put the problem on jsfiddle, ty very much, I can't seem to change the code no matter what I do, which is strange

Comment: @webmasters You didn't mention it is in an `iframe`. You can not edit it (unless its domain, protocol and port matched your site).

Comment: Is it in an iframe? I see only a javacript link

Comment: @webmasters Look at the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is overriding it with JavaScript. You can easily target the elements with jQuery and change their inline CSS.